# Run php from command line with a text file

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have a php script test.php and I need to run this file with a .txt file which has some commands and need to echo the result.

The script is running, I have no problem reading the text file if it is in the directory and output the result. reading a text file from CLI is not working.

```
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');  // this is not working.
$moves = array();
// $stdin = fopen('robotmoves.txt',  'r'); This line works
$i = 0;
while (($line = fgets($stdin)) !== FALSE) {
    if (is_numeric(trim($line))) {
        $no_of_blocks = (int) $line;
    }
}
```

in the command line i run

```
php test.php ../robotmoves.txt
```

The robotmoves.txt is in the htdocs folder

Comment: `php test.php < ../robotmoves.txt`?

Comment: Note you don't have to open `stdin`, you can just use the predefined constant `STDIN` https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php